# Find Latest record by date for each distinct column value

Tags: mysql

I am working with a dataset with a similar format to the following:

```
Table: Account
*-----------*----------*-------------*
|     id    |  amount  |   date      |
*-----------*----------*-------------*
|      1    |   100    |  01/01/2016 |
|      2    |   100    |  01/02/2016 |
|      3    |   100    |  01/03/2016 |
|      4    |   200    |  01/04/2016 |
|      5    |   200    |  01/05/2016 |
|      6    |   200    |  01/06/2016 |
|      7    |   300    |  01/07/2016 |
|      8    |   300    |  01/08/2016 |
|      9    |   300    |  01/09/2016 |
|     10    |   400    |  01/10/2016 |
*-----------*----------*-------------*
```

I need a query to return that returns the most recent record for every distinct value in the table. So, the above table would return

```
*-----------*----------*-------------*
|     id    |  amount  |   date      |
*-----------*----------*-------------*
|      3    |   100    |  01/03/2016 |
|      6    |   200    |  01/06/2016 |
|      9    |   300    |  01/09/2016 |
|     10    |   400    |  01/10/2016 |
*-----------*----------*-------------*
```

I am still new to subqueries but I tried the following

```
SELECT a.id, a.amount, a.date FROM account a WHERE a.date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM account)
```

However this only return the latest date. How can I get the latest date for every distinct value in the amount column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need amount:

```
SELECT amount, MAX(date) from myTable group by amount
```

If you need more data:

```
SELECT * from myTable where (amount, date) IN (
    SELECT amount, MAX(date) as date from table group by amount
)
```

Or maybe this will run faster:

```
SELECT * from myTable A WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM myTable B
    WHERE A.date < B.date
      AND A.amount = B.amount
)
```